# Dock process creates lock screen images continuously

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, bug, lockscreen

[image][image][image]I noticed today that my disk is completely full despite the fact that it was half full just yesterday. OmniDiskSweeper revealed that in private/var/folders/gn loads of lock screen.png screenshots that are being made automatically every second. It seems Dock process is responsible for it. Couldn't have found any solutions anywhere. Is there any way to stop it?
P.S. MacBook Pro 2017, macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: It's not quite clear, are you saying the Dock is automatically taking screenshots and filling up your drive?

Comment: Exactly
And all these screenshots are in the private/var/folders/gn

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode. This sounds like spyware

Comment: Doesn't help. In the safe mode the same problem. After rebooting Mac, disk is half empty as it should be, but screenshots are still being made and filling up the disk again.

Comment: This is **not** normal behavior and the only applications I've ever seen take screen captures like this is remote monitoring software (a.k.a *spyware* - it just dependnds on whose doing the watching).  I would backup your data and wipe your drive and do a fresh install of macOS via [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Answer (score 0):

After changing my desktop background, it stopped all of a sudden

Comment: The same happened to me.  I had setup my Mac to rotate the desktop background image every minute. When I lost access to the shared folder that I was taking these images from, Dock started to create these screenshots every minute...  Going to the preferences and changing this setting solved the issue.